# Parsing levels of XML in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Here is my XML. I am going to have many Degrees, each Degree will have many schools, and each school will have many Specializations. The Page will gave three dropdowns. I am not asking for all the code to preform all the onclicks nested dropdown updates. (unless someone has some cool recurrence pattern what would work.

This problem I am having is when I ask for the degree from the Degrees node and add the text() to the dropdown I get all the text from the degree, school, spec... so what I want is a dropdown with "Degree 1", but I get "Degree 1 School 1 Spec...", I am sure you get the idea, I have tried adding "Degrees.filter, and children" but then I get nothing.

I need to get a handle on how to parse the XML with nested nodes once level at a time.

Thanks for your time.

```
<Degrees>
  <Degree>
  Degree 1
  <Schools>
    <School>School 1
      <Specializations>
       <Specialization>Specialization 1</Specialization>
       <Specialization>Specialization 2</Specialization>
      </Specializations>
    </School>
    <School>School 2
      <Specializations>
       <Specialization>Specialization 3</Specialization>
       <Specialization>Specialization 4</Specialization>
      </Specializations>
    </School>
  </Schools>
  </Degree>
</Degrees>
```

The current jQuery

```
var Degrees = $(PID).find('Degrees');
    Degrees.find("Degree").filter("Degree").each(function () {
    var select = $('#degree');
    var value = $(this).text();
    select.append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
    });
```

The HTML

```
<select id="degree">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Degree --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing, this also allows me to sort the drop-down. Please comment if anyone has any other ideas.

```
var degreelist = new Array();
                $(xml).find('PID[id="' + PID + '"] Degrees Degree').each(function () {
                    var Item = new Object();
                    Item.Id = $(this).attr("id");
                    Item.value = $(xml).find('Degrees Degree[id=' + Item.Id + ']').text();
                    degreelist.push(Item);
                });

                degreelist.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.value.text > b.value.text) return 1;
                    else if (a.value.text < b.value.text) return -1;
                    else return 0
                })

                for (var i = 0; i < degreelist.length; i++) {
                    $('#degree').append("<option value='" + degreelist[i].Id + "'>" + degreelist[i].value + "</option>");
                }
```